# Fix zsh _arguments options (--whatever) completion after non-options (noDashes) input

Tags: zsh, completion

I would like to allow completion for `--flags` after other input in [my gradle completion script](https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-completion/blob/master/_gradle#L21-L70), but `_arguments` seems to require that

> specs that describe option flags must precede specs that describe non-option ("positional" or "normal") arguments of the analyzed line (from the [zsh completion docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Control-Functions))

In other words: `command foo --o[TAB]` does nothing, but `command --o[TAB]` works fine. Is there any way to configure `_arguments` or do I need to use other [control functions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Control-Functions)?

**NOTE:** Separate completion functions do not seem like an option in my case as the inputs are not in a fixed list (gradle tasks are arbitrary and multiple can be specified, `gradle myfoo mybar --o[TAB]` must work).

Comment: Have a look at the git completion functions, they work like that (`git clone --[TAB]` for example (`--bare, --branch, ...`))

Comment: @TomRegner that's a good idea — I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Git completion (https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Completion/Unix/Command/_git) uses completion functions per subcommand (e.g. `_git_clone()`). In my case, the Gradle task list is dynamic, and multiple tasks can be specified, so using the same approach doesn't seem feasible. I shall add that to the question.

Comment: @TomRegner after taking another look, your suggestion was correct. Git allows arbitrary branch names (after `git checkout`, say) and will provide completion of options afterward. I could use the logic from git completion to achieve my answer below. Thank you!

Comment: Very cool! I like that ;-)

Comment: @TomRegner If you submit an answer with you comment, I'll award you the bounty.

Comment: Nah, the comment is not really worth that much -- seems to be too late anyway (If I had extracted the info from the git-stuff, but I didn't) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this with [this commit](https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-completion/commit/16b04e413c0c264a98ac65375968b0fe26573eaa) at least to allow options after 1 task is specified.

The trick is to set the state within `_arguments` with `:->statename`, reset the context to the next word, and provide a wildcard matcher that matches non-command words and use `_arguments` again.

There's almost certainly a way to allow options specified after an arbitrary number of words and avoid some duplication, but this is a workable start.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to be able to type something like `vim foo -[TAB]` and have a list auto expand to show flags and switches, where currently you have to type `vim -[TAB]` to get your flags and switches and then type `foo`, yes?

Hopefully I am understanding your question correctly.

My current zsh completion options might be able to help with this, as I can do what I described, which seems to be what you are asking for?  It has been quite a while sense I set these up so I don't remember precisely what each one does. What I belive you want though is the `setopt COMPLETE_IN_WORD` , `unset LIST_AMBIGUOUS`, as well as the `zstyle ':completion::approximate*:*' prefix-needed false` options.  If I am wrong someone please correct me.

I have included what I use in my zsh as my completion section. I have tested this as standalone and it works on my zsh as is.

```
#{{{ Completion Stuff
zmodload -i zsh/complist
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
bindkey -M viins '\C-i' complete-word
# Faster! (?)
zstyle ':completion::complete:*' use-cache 1
# case insensitive completion
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}' \
  'r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'
zstyle ':completion:*' verbose yes
zstyle ':completion:*:descriptions' format '%B%d%b'
zstyle ':completion:*:messages' format '%d'
zstyle ':completion:*:warnings' format 'No matches for: %d'
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
# generate descriptions with magic.
zstyle ':completion:*' auto-description 'specify: %d'
# Don't prompt for a huge list, page it!
zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-prompt '%S%M matches%s'
# Don't prompt for a huge list, menu it!
zstyle ':completion:*:default' menu 'select=0'
# Have the newer files last so I see them first
zstyle ':completion:*' file-sort modification reverse
# color code completion
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors "=(#b) #([0-9]#)*=36=31"
unsetopt LIST_AMBIGUOUS
setopt  COMPLETE_IN_WORD
# Separate man page sections.
zstyle ':completion:*:manuals' separate-sections true
#
zstyle ':completion:*' list-separator 'fREW'
# complete with a menu for xwindow ids
zstyle ':completion:*:windows' menu on=0
zstyle ':completion:*:expand:*' tag-order all-expansions
# more errors allowed for large words and fewer for small words
zstyle ':completion:*:approximate:*' max-errors 'reply=(  $((  ($#PREFIX+$#SUFFIX)/3  ))  )'
# Errors format
zstyle ':completion:*:corrections' format '%B%d (errors %e)%b'
# Don't complete stuff already on the line
zstyle ':completion::*:(rm|vi):*' ignore-line true
# Don't complete directory we are already in (../here)
zstyle ':completion:*' ignore-parents parent pwd
zstyle ':completion::approximate*:*' prefix-needed false
```

Comment: I think you're partially understanding my question. It sounds like you're suggesting that I configure my completion script using `setopt` and `zstyle` commands, but I get the sense that you think I'm approaching this for my personal zsh configuration. My intent is to provide a better completion script for our Gradle users. I don't want to configure this for just any completion, I specifically want to address this for gradle-completion.